# Implementing ICC in Keras model

Tags: keras, intraclass-correlation

I have a custom ResNet-50 that I am training with a set of 3D brain images to predict the category of atrophy in patients. However, the scale for categorization is a visual scale, as opposed to a quantitative scale, so there is subjective bias from the different radiologists (5) who read the images. My training set is reaching close to 100% categorical accuracy (levels: 0-3) but my validation set maxes out around 65%. This is interesting because it is almost the same as the Intraclass coefficient between raters in a smaller sample where all 5 radiologists read the scans. Therefore, I do not think the model is overfitting, but is constrained by the subjectivity. I have the data for which person rated the scan so I have two ideas and I am open to any others.

First, is there a way to add the rater (1-5) as a covariate in the network to account for variance due to who gave the rating?

Second, is there a way to implement ICC as an accuracy metric in Keras? I currently have TFRecord files with the image as a feature and the rating as a label. My first thought is to add the rater as another feature, don't use it in training, and then somehow pull it when the accuracy metric is calculated for a batch, and then calculate ICC (e.g. for batch size 32, training would give 32 class predictions, I would pull the 32 rater indicators, merge into a DataFrame, then calculate ICC). But I have no idea how to start to do this and I am having trouble finding online documentation.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.